# Rails add more ajax form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a rails form where I would like to add the functionality to add more fields to to-many relations in nested form. I have a form which is like this;

```
= form_for @company do |f|
  = f.label :name, "Company name"
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.label :homepage_url, "Company website"
  = f.text_field :homepage_url, placeholder: "www.mycompanywebsite.com"
  = render "domains_form"
  %div{class: "add_more_button"}
    = link_to "Add more domains", "add_domain", remote: true, data: {mini: "true", theme: "b", iconpos: "left", icon: "plus",  role: "button"}, id:"more_email_domains"
  = f.submit "Continue", data: {theme: "a", icon: "arrow-r", iconpos: "right"}
```

The partial "domain_form" looks like this;

```
= fields_for @company do |f|
  = f.fields_for :domains do |d|
    = d.label :identifier, "Domain name"
    = d.text_field :identifier
```

This gives me the error as this;

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: %div
2:   = fields_for @company do |f|
```

It seems like partial could not find the @company instance but how could it be ? Since, the main template has the access to instance, shouldn't the partial also have access to instance. Do I need to pass the company instance as the locale exclusively.

The problem is more likely in fields_for call as I am not using it on any form_builder object rather using it as a global method. As rails api suggests that the method can be used standalone http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_form, such that the first fields_for takes parent object and the following one takes child, this should work fine on my assumption. Could you please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not now how to write haml syntax but have you tried to loop through your to-many association?

```
# _form.html.erb
<%= @company.domains.each do |domain| %>
  <%= render "domain_form", domain: domain %>
<% end %>

# _domain_form.html.erb
<%= fields_for "company[domains_attributes][], domain do |d| %>
  <%= d.label :identifier, "Domain name" %>
  <%= d.text_field :identifier %>
<% end %>

# company.rb
attr_accessible ..., :domains_attributes
has_many :domains
accepts_nested_attributes_for :domains
```

I hope this helps.